# How to build Kernel version 4.0.4 using Git?

Tags: kernel, git

I should like to build a 4.0 kernel by cloning a repository as described in [this web page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)
which quotes the text :

> git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-.git

I can't find an appropriate URL to follow the word 'clone'. If anyone can suggest a page, I would be grateful.

The 'Git' link on [this page](https://www.kernel.org/) isn't helpful.

Comment: Why don't you get an already built kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Because I want to patch it

Comment: Why don't you patch an existing Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: I think you want `git://kernel.ubuntu.com/virgin/linux-stable.git v4.0.4` see [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.4-wily/SOURCES) and [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.4-wily/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ubuntu kernel 4.0.4 yet. You can get mainline kernel deb packages from [Ubuntu kernel ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) or build a mainline kernel from kernel.org.

Mainline stable kernel source can be cloned from

git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

The branch version you need can be cloned by

```
git clone --branch linux-4.0.y --single-branch git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

You will get 4.0.4.

But you need to take in account, that it is not debianized. And that patch won't apply right away.

And also the build guide you found won't be helpful either.

Comment: I only want to make small change to the source  as described in the fix for this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1426583

Comment: Build a mainline kernel then, if you badly need using 4.0.4 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Fine, but how do I get the sources?

Comment: Or you can build a debian kernel. it will work in Ubuntu. You can find link at that bug report. Mainline sources can be found at kernel.org.

Comment: Only using HTTP though, I would like to get them using Git as I originally asked.

Comment: You are wrong. All mainline kernel source is in git.

Comment: Please tell me the URL,as I originally asked

Comment: Please read the updated answer.

Comment: The mainline one is `git clone   git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`

Comment: This will be 4.1.

Comment: It will be whatever you ask for when you do a checkout.

Comment: That is not correct. You will never get 4.0.4 from torvalds.git. You can get 4.0, or 4.1rc. 4.0 has been copied to stable and updated there.

Comment: Agreed. (These are extra characters to make it to the minimum).